# Getting error "Invalid request. Sub or function not defined in PPT VBA"

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have written code for opening a PPT presentation on my system and store only the ppt file  name in a variable. That ppt file will call one more saved module. My code is given below:

```
Sub PPTTest()
  Dim PPT As Object

  Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

  Dim fldr As FileDialog
  Dim sItem As String
  Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
  With fldr
    .Title = "Select a File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = ""
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
  End With
  Set fldr = Nothing


  PPT.Presentations.Open sItem, , , False
  Filename = Mid$(sItem, InStrRev(sItem, "\") + 1, Len(sItem))


  PPT.Run "fileName!Module1.KillSpecificSlide"

 End Sub
```

But after debugging in the line

```
PPT.Run "fileName!Module1.KillSpecificSlide"
```

it shows the error

> Invalid request. Sub or function not defined.

When I have written the same code as

```
PPT.Run "BOD.pptx!Module1.KillSpecificSlide"
```

it works fine. But when I store the same name in a variable and pass it through the code its shows error.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: How about `PPT.RUN filename & "!Module1.KillSpecificFile"`

Comment: @MigueIH it shows same error...

Comment: I think @MiguelH solution will solve the problem. If still getting Error may be the `Module1`  or  sub .`KillSpecificFile` is missing. Also how does BDO.pptx (macro free) have a module  and code saved in it.

Comment: Have you checked that the value held in `filename` contains the full filename?

Comment: See MiguelH's suggestion but use PPT.Application.Run instead of PPT.Run